# Circuit diagram question - microcontroller input protection

Tags: circuit-design, protection

I'm new to electronics, and I would like someone with more experience to look at my diagram.

The circuit consists of:

- a 5 V regulator (from a 12 V input) that powers the microcontroller
- a pull-up resistor, and
- a transistor.

The "0 V to +80 V" input is idling at ~12 V, but occasionally drops to 0 V (for a period of 10 ms) followed by a ~80 V spike.

The goal is for microcontroller to count those spikes, by reading the value of PB0 (pin 5).

My question is: Will this work? If not, what do I need to make it work? :)

Circuit diagram:

[image: circuit diagram]

---

Update

Input signal:

[image: input signal]

<sub>(Original image source: [tinypic.com](http://i65.tinypic.com/jkygk3.jpg))</sub>

Comment: This will surely damage the NPN transistor. You also don't need the full spike's amplitude. Read a bit on voltage dividers and BJTs.

Comment: For voltages that high I'd consider galvanic isolation, unless you know that it is reasonably clean from noise.

Comment: Are the spikes consistent?  Are they always 80.0V? Or are they 40-80 V spikes?  What is the time width of the spikes?  Are they always the same width?  Are you trying to filter out the spikes and count the 0-12 transitions?  Or are you really trying to trigger off the spikes?

Answer (score 1):

You need an attenuator, not an amplifier (BJT). Here is a crude circuit. You may need a 4th diode depending on your MC input threshold. The zener voltage can be adjusted to get the input threshold to be what you want. Do you want >80V? or it that just typical.

What is the spike width, you may want a small cap in parallel with the MC input to filter out spurious noise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe97K9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you want to know when the signal goes from 12V to 0V, use a smaller zener, about 9V. And with all that EMI noise, you definitely want a cap at the MC input. But if you put too large of a value, you will delay your signal. You need to find the right compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Since your "signal" is 0 or 80 V while your uC only needs 0 or 5 V, there really is no need to use a transistor.

Obviously we the uC needs to be protected against the 80 V. We can simply use a voltage divider for this, a voltage divider will:

- lower the 80 V to 5 V suitable for the uC
- limit the current (from the 80 V input) to safe a level such that the uC cannot be damaged.

I would simply use:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0VDmG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 do not need to have exactly the value specified. As long as you keep their ration the same (R1/R2 must be constant) and do not make them too low in value (I would not make R1 lower than 20 k ohm) this should work. Assuming the 80 V pulses can deliver enough current (as shown only 750 uA is needed).

R1 and R2 divide 80 V to 5 V, which is also the uC's supply voltage. The uC decides between zero or one at VCC / 2 so at 2.5 V. That means that at the 80 V input only voltages above 40 V are considered "one". All below is considered "zero" so the 12V idling voltage will be ignored.

Comment: Make sure R1 is rated for more than 75V

Comment: If i use a 100k/6.8k divider, wouldn't that result in the same read (PB0) for both 0v and 12v ? the 80v is a spike that CAN occur after the signal has been pulled to 0v. See this oscilloscope image for the signal http://i65.tinypic.com/jkygk3.jpg

Comment: *wouldn't that result in the same read (PB0) for both 0v and 12v ?* Like I wrote:  All voltages below 40 V are considered "zero". It was unclear to me that you wanted to count 12 V pulses and the 80 V is just a spike. Then use the circuit suggested by Mattman in the other answer.

Comment: i want to count every time the signal goes to 0v